# Desire2Learn Valence API PUT says Not Found when the record is there

Tags: desire2learn

I am new to the Valence API and have formulated the following request (note I am accessing the sandboxu.brightspace.com instance assigned to us as a new client of D2L):

PUT /d2l/api/lp/1.6/users/1900?x_a...

(auth info does work and I am not including it here)

the content/post body is

```
{
    "Activation":
    {
        "IsActive":"True"
    },
    "userName":"NCU.A5",
    "OrgDefinedId":"NCU.A5",
    "FirstName":"NCU",
    "MiddleName":"J",
    "LastName":"A5",
    "ExternalEmail":"NCU.A5@desire2learncom.desire2learndemo.com"
}
```

Note that I do a GET with exactly the same url and it successfully retrieves the following:

```
{
    "OrgId":6607,
    "UserId":1900,
    "FirstName":"NCU",
    "MiddleName":null,
    "LastName":"A5",
    "UserName":"NCU.A5",
    "ExternalEmail":"NCU.A5@desire2learncom.desire2learndemo.com",
    "OrgDefinedId":"NCU.A5",
    "UniqueIdentifier":"NCU.A5",
    "Activation":{"IsActive":true},
    "DisplayName":"NCU A5"
}
```

So the userid is valid.

However, this PUT request returns a 404/Not Found. I reviewed the Valance API online doc and it looks to me like the request block has all of the correct elements. This request should update the middle name from null to "J".

I am sure I am doing something wrong but I can't find it.

Comment: I just attempted this call on my test system with an Admin account and I received a 200 success. Have you confirmed that the account you're making this call under has the permissions required to make a change to a user record? For example, an instructor may have permission to GET user records but not update them with a PUT.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I was using RestSharp per the D2L sample code to formulate the request. I set the PostBody to the json string. Per a problem we found documented on CodeGur for RestSharp, it reserialized the string, replacing all of the quotes with escaped quotes (\"). I inspected the RestSharp request before it was sent, and it did NOT have these extra characters, but it placed them in at the time the request was processed.

I commented out this line:
 //string postBody = SimpleJson.SerializeObject(postBodyValues);
and changed the AddBody() to accept the unserialized object and it worked.